# How can I fix an SSD that causes a POST failure but works in an enclosure?

Tags: ssd, bios, post, enclosures

My OS boot drive appears to have failed today: after the computer resumed from sleep (for reference, Windows 11 on an Intel NUC), the system reports unsuccessful POST attempts, and will not boot.

In the BIOS, the SSD is not detected at all (no SATA drive detected). However, I can place the drive in an external USB enclosure and use it without issues.  I also placed the SSD in another computer and observed the same POST fault.

I suspect my SSD is close to permanent failure, but I'm curious if this is a known type of non-terminal issue and if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Similar symptoms documented in this post l question: https://superuser.com/questions/887306/ssd-not-detected-after-2-days-of-power-off

Comment: Just because the system volume can be mounted doesn’t mean the other partitions are not corrupt (EFI) or the system is actually bootable (system file corruption) only the drive is mountable (again does not eliminate file corruption). The linked question is NA since Windows 11 does not support Legacy Mode